# Why is this call to a react-native native module blocking the UI?

Tags: react-native

As advised in the docs, I moved some long data-fetching code into a native module to free the JS thread, but I observe that this is still blocking the UI. Why is that and what can I do to avoid that ?

The native module is called from JS as so :

```js
MyNativeModule.fetch(path).then( data => dispatchData(data) )
```

The native method looks like this (it uses the Android Firebase SDK):

```java
@ReactMethod
public void fetch(final String path, final Promise promise) {
    root.child(path).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                promise.resolve(castSnapshot(snapshot));
            } else {
                promise.resolve(null);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            promise.reject(firebaseError.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

The `castSnapshot` method converts the Firebase `DataSnapshot` object into a `WriteableMap`. I can share the implementation if that is useful.

What I observed is that even if I replace `promise.resolve(castSnapshot(snapshot));` by `castSnapshot(snapshot); promise.resolve(null);`, the call is blocking the UI : so it is not sending the data over the bridge that is the culprit. If the amount of data is large, `castSnapshot` can take some time, and this is clearly what is blocking.

Even if this code is long running, shouldn't moving it to a native module free the UI? What do I not get about this?

Many thanks.

Comment: I have the same problem. I thought native modules run on a different thread, however, it seems it don't.

Comment: @RomShiri yeah.. i think if we want to use native modules for perf reasons we have to manage threading ourselves. From the docs : "Native modules should not have any assumptions about what thread they are being called on [...]  If a blocking call is required, the heavy work should be dispatched to an internally managed worker thread, and any callbacks distributed from there."

Comment: i found out the same. Ryans approach was necessary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try wrapping the `root.child` line in a new Thread instance, like this:

```
@ReactMethod
public void fetch(final String path, final Promise promise) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            root.child(path)...
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Comment: is there an iOs implementation for something like that. I have a similar problem, a native module starting a thread that doesn't stop, and if I run it more than 4 times, it crashes the app, memory profile indicates a memory leak. I'll appreciate any help I can get @Ryan

Comment: For iOS, it's been a while since I've dealt with this but I think you'd only need to create a secondary queue by overriding `methodQueue` as described here: https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-ios#threading. I can't comment on the memory leak without seeing code.

Comment: I created a gist here: https://gist.github.com/boblitex/3098cd0d50bf09a800ecd5b7b45cafad

I use a library that uses a native module under the hood. (React-native-ping). but looks like every ping creates a thread and doesn't destroy after resolving. 
I'll look into threading too, struggling all week with this